# how to add infoWindowAdapters for multiple markers having different values?

Tags: java, android, marker, infowindow

```
 Marker drMark=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(drLoc).title("Lahore").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
 Marker selfMark=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(curLocation).title("Lahore").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.passengermarker)));
```

I am trying to add infoWindow to multiple markers in maps Activity. But the infoWindow adapter is showing the same data on all the markers after being initialized in onMapsReady. I want to show infoWindow on all the markers with their own information i.e. marker infoWindows to be initialized individually so that data becomes relevant.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: it got replace gimme a moment

Comment: check out plz @GhostCat

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is by using tags for markers to differentiate between the markers in the infoWindowAdapter section. It is an easier way to do this job I thought.

```
selfMark=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(curLocation).title("Lahore").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.passengermarker)));
                selfMark.setTag("user");

 drMark=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(drLoc).title("Lahore").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
                    drMark.setTag("driver");
```

this section for InfoWinfoAdapter:

```
     mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                                return null;
                            }

                                @Override
                                public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
                                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.driver_inf, null);

                                final TextView tvEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.emailDrive);
                                final TextView tvname = view.findViewById(R.id.nameDrive);
                                final TextView tvlocality = view.findViewById(R.id.localityDrive);
                                    if(marker.getTag().equals("driver")){
                                        tvEmail.setText("Driver");
                                    }
                                    else if (marker.getTag().equals("user")){
                                        tvEmail.setText("Passenger");
                                    }


                                tvname.setText(dC.getName());
                                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(passengerAct.this, Locale.getDefault());
                                try {
                                    List<Address> adr = gc.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, 1);
                                    Address address = adr.get(0);
                                    tvlocality.setText(address.getLocality() + "," + address.getCountryName());
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return view;
                            }
                        });
```